# What is the right way to create a ruby method to get the number of spaces in the start of the string without opening String Class

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a program to create folder structure from the text file.
In that I need to get the spaces that comes before any word in the given line.
How can I implement this functionality in ruby without opening String class?
I come from C# and it's very easy to extract methods in it. But I don't know how rubyists approach the same problem!

Here is the half of the program that I have written.

```
require "FileUtils"

@lines_array = []

def file_to_array
file = File.open("fs.txt", "r") do |file|  
    file.each_line do |line|  
      @lines_array << line.rstrip
      @lines_array.reject! {|l| l.empty?}
    end
  end
end

def creation
    @lines_array.each do |i| 
        if (  /(.+)\.(\w+)/ =~ i  ) 
            FileUtils.touch i
        else
            FileUtils.mkdir_p i
        end
    end
end

def count_space
    beginning =  s.length - s.lstrip.length
    beginning
end
```

How can I extract logic from  file_to_array method? And how can I implement and use count_space on elements of `@lines_array`?

Comment: can you please provide more information as to what the file contains and how you extracts each file name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to be able to call the `#count_spaces` method on your lines.  Well there are three ways to approach this.

1. Open up the String class (what you don't want to do)
2. Create a class that inherits from Sting
3. Create a class that contains the string as an instance variable (this is probably your prefered method)

**Open the class**

```
class String
  def count_spaces
     #code here
  end
end
```

**Inherited class**

```
class FileSystemLine < String
  def count_spaces
     #code here
  end
end
```

**Class with data in instance variable**

```
class FileSystemLine
  def initialize(line)
    @line = line
  end

  def count_spaces
     #code here 
     # make sure that code acts on @line
     # like @line.length - @line.strip.length
  end

  # If you want to keep string functionalities, you could look up ruby delegation or use this simple method_missing method
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if @line.respond_to?(method)
      @line.__send__(method, *args, &block) 
     else
       super
     end
  end
end
```

Just remember to initialize the class.

Option 1. remains the same, option 2. and option 3. both look like this: `line = FilSystemLine.new(line)`

So your code would look like:

```
@lines_array = []
def file_to_array
  file = File.open("fs.txt", "r") do |file|  
    file.each_line do |line|  
      @lines_array << FileSystemLine.new(line.rstrip)
      @lines_array.reject! {|l| l.empty?}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not able to give you a thumbs up because I don't have that much reputation, but this is exactly what I wanted to ask. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain why we you wrote method_missing? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: So method_missing is the method ruby calls when an method is called on an object, where the method is not defined for that object. By overwriting that method, we can send any methods that `@line` responds to to `@line`. Otherwise, if you were to call `FileSystemLine.new('string').empty?` you would get a `NoMethodError`.  You can forward methods using "delegators", too, which makes it nicer to declare which methods you would like to delegate to other objects.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution:

```
s = '   aaa  ' #3 spaces in start and after `aa` there are two spaces

s[/\A */].size # for blank spaces in start of string
=> 3
s[/ *\z/].size # for blank spaces a the end of string
=> 2
```